# Is it a bad idea to forward a suspicious email with an attachment - even to a secure address for analysis?

Tags: email

The more servers the message passes through the more potential of the attack to execute successfully? (0-day etc). Or is this paranoia?

Instead: Delete, disconnect from network, and phone security team?

Comment: There are malicious emails that target mail servers but a user needs to interact with them. if you are talking about the mere *forwarding* then the answer is NO, not at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servers passing messages is really not a problem.

Your mail client has already opened the email so you forwarding it on is not opening your machine up to any further risk.

The mailbox to send these things to is usually on a machine that has strong security and sand boxing capabilities (or can be created on the fly as a VM)

If concerned, always delete, however forwarding on to your analysis team is essential if they are to understand it.